# How to schedule a record field change to run after a specific amount of time

Tags: visual-workflow

I would like every Lead that meets certain criteria to be marked as stale (toggling a custom field) and reassigned if it's been inactive for 24 hours (LastModifiedDate > 24 hours ago). I'm trying to use a Flow with a scheduled path. The issue is that if the Lead is modified after the Flow is triggered, I assume the original flow would still be running. I would need a way to cancel the previous Flow if a new one is activated on this record. My backup plan is to just run a batch class every few hours, but that's less ideal.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the above scenario a schedulable batch apex would be a better option
2. You can schedule the batch class to run midnight
3. Due to its asynchronous behaviour you get increased governor limits by which you can process large data volumes
4. Flows on the other hand are synchronous so it may be possible that in near future your flow would encounter System.Limit Exception every now and then

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thank you.